# Add a custom action to the list as a button in sp 2013

Tags: 2013

I need to add a custom button to run my code over the list. I was working with SP 2007 before and I was adding the button in the actions menu top of the list.

How can I get the same functionality on sp 2013?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it very much possible inn SP2013.
You can reference from below site as a starting point:

with Visual sutdio : [Link](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/custom-actions-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

with Sharepoint Designer: [Link](http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-a-custom-action-in-2-steps-with-sharepoint-designer/)